# cumulative total in sql

Tags: mysql, sql, database, oracle

I have this table. I need to count:

1. Total number of bricks by cumulative total(total_count)
2. Number of bricks of each color cumulative total (running_total_per_colour)

```
brick_id     colour shape   weight
1            blue   cube    1
2            blue   pyramid 2
3            red    cube    1
4            red    cube    2
5            red    pyramid 3
6            green  pyramid 1
```

How can i make this with SQL

Comment: Edit your question and show the results you want.

Comment: @GordonLinoff yes i am looking for window functions.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Yes thank you a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this.

```
SELECT A.*, COUNT(*) OVER() CUMMULATIVE_TOTAL,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY COLOUR ORDER BY BRICK_ID) RUNNING_TOTAL
FROM TABLE1 A;
```

[DB_FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/88ce4/4)

Answer (score 0):

Are you just looking for window functions?

```
select t.*,
       row_number() over (order by brick_id) as cumulative_bricks,
       sum(case when colour = 'blue' then 1 else 0 end) over (order by brick_id) as blue_bricks,
       sum(case when colour = 'red' then 1 else 0 end) over (order by brick_id) as red_bricks,
       sum(case when colour = 'green' then 1 else 0 end) over (order by brick_id) as green_bricks
from t;
```